# Two queries that should be equivalent are returning different results

Tags: mysql, database, sql

I have two queries. The first returns some results and the second one returns nothing. Here they are.

This one returns some results:

```
select md5(concat(ad.line1, ad.line2, ad.city, s.name, ad.zip, group_concat(distinct c.name))) id,
       group_concat(distinct c.name) customer_names,
       count(distinct c.name) number_of_customers,
       ad.line1,
       ad.line2,
       ad.city,
       s.name state_name,
       ad.zip,
       a.import_id
  from address ad
  join account_address aa on aa.address_id = ad.id
  join account a on aa.account_id = a.id
  join import i on a.import_id = i.id
  join customer c on a.customer_id = c.id
  join state s on ad.state_id = s.id
 where a.import_id = 188
group by s.name, city, zip, line1, line2
```

This returns nothing:

```
select * from
(select md5(concat(ad.line1, ad.line2, ad.city, s.name, ad.zip, group_concat(distinct c.name))) id,
       group_concat(distinct c.name) customer_names,
       count(distinct c.name) number_of_customers,
       ad.line1,
       ad.line2,
       ad.city,
       s.name state_name,
       ad.zip,
       a.import_id
  from address ad
  join account_address aa on aa.address_id = ad.id
  join account a on aa.account_id = a.id
  join import i on a.import_id = i.id
  join customer c on a.customer_id = c.id
  join state s on ad.state_id = s.id
group by s.name, city, zip, line1, line2) v
where v.import_id = 188
```

I'm completely bamboozled. Any ideas?

My DBMS is MySQL.

Comment: I'd recommend you to `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'` until you get comfortable with how `GROUP BY` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second query is abusing `MySQL` extension to `GROUP BY` which allows to select unaggregated columns.

`import_id` is selected from a random record per group in the second query, and it's not guaranteed it will be `188`. But the query checks for it after the `GROUP BY`.

Sample data:

```
grouper   value
1         1
1         1
1         2
1         3
2         1
2         2
2         3
```

First query:

```
SELECT  grouper, value
FROM    mytable
WHERE   value = 1

grouper   value
1         1
1         1
2         1
```

Since `WHERE` is executed before `GROUP BY`, this query will only consider records holding `value = 1` (which were returned on the previous stage):

```
SELECT   grouper, COUNT(*)
FROM     mytable
WHERE    value = 1
GROUP BY
         grouper

grouper   COUNT(*)
1         2
2         1
```

Second query:

```
SELECT   grouper, COUNT(*), value
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY
         grouper

grouper   COUNT(*)  value
1         4         2
2         3         3
```

Since `value` is not grouped and not aggregated, it can be taken from *any* record within the group! In this case that was taken from the last records or appropriate groups (but could be taken from any other records as well).

```
SELECT   *
FROM     (
         SELECT   grouper, COUNT(*), value
         FROM     mytable
         GROUP BY
                  grouper
         ) q
WHERE    value = 1

-- no rows
```

Since there were no record with `value = 1` on the previous stage (it happened so that the values were taken from the other records), no record satisfies the `WHERE` condition.